# getting error when making parameter in angular property or signature expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I get an error when trying to make parameter when there is a number first which is required from openweathermap because in their api to get data from rain is 3h. so I have to write data.rain.3h and it does not work.

```
rain: {
    3h: number;
}
```

Comment: use `data.rain['3h']` instead

Answer (score 1):

This is a Javascript error, not an Angular one.

The correct way to use the object is:

```
rain: {
    "3h": number;
}
```

Notice the quotemark.

Then, to use it, you have to do: `data.rain['3h']`

Comment: when typing data.rain.['3h'] i get error identifier expected

Comment: @ErdonSmilly Remove the `.` from before the `[` it should just be `data.rain['3h']`

Comment: It means that `data.rain` is undefined. Your problem is before that... The `data` variable does not contain a `rain` property.